# Why does for...in loop iterate through function names

Tags: javascript, for-loop, internet-explorer-8

While testing some JavaScrpt code in IE8 I'm experiencing some strange behaviour when doing a simple for..in loop:

```
var categories = ['for', 'bar', 'steam'];
for(var key in categories) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

Outputs:

```
0
1
2
forEach
map
filter
reduce
indexOf
end
```

Which includes the Array prototype functions, right? That's definitely not the way it should work. Why is that?

Btw, it works of course when changing the loop to `for (var key=0; key < categories.length, key++)`.

Comment: `for...in` notation is made to iterate over the properties of objects. Look at the second warning on the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering so fast and solving the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are probably using a library that extends `Array.prototype`. The reason it doesn't happen in other browsers is that they already support those methods natively. Since IE doesn't support it, there's some code that adds it in JS, which makes the methods enumerable.

That's one of the reasons why you shouldn't use `for in` with arrays.

The other is the fact that `for in` does not guarantee order of iteration, and though it does work in most browsers, it's explicitly left as undefined behavior by the specification. John Resig himself filed a bug against chrome http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=883 and it was closed as won't fix, since there's no requirement that properties need to be ordered

Stick to using a standard loop

Comment: What do you mean with "and though it does not work"? It works but, it enumerates the properties unordered, as you described. Also I do not think there is sth wich "makes the methods enumerable", all the methods added to your array are enumerable by default.

Comment: @Nappy, I can't tell what you're saying. I said that in most browsers, it does work (iterate in the right order). If you add properties yourself, they will be enumerable, but native methods are not enumerable

Comment: Ah, sorry it was a language issue, you really meant sth. like "and thats how it works in most browsers". Your usage of though confused me :)

Comment: @Nappy Your usage of sth confused me... we don't use IM speak here at SO. I still can't tell what your point is, you couldn't tell that "it does work" was referring to iterating over an array in the right order ?

Answer (score 2):

`for..in` is meant for objects *not* arrays. Use a regular `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
  console.log(categories[i]);
}
```

`for...in` will work for arrays when you don't care about index but it's not advisable. The problem you're experiencing is because `for...in` looks up *all* the properties of the object, including those in the prototype, this is why it's recommended to always check if the property is actually in the object.

```
for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: It's recommended if you don't want to look at the inherited properties, sometimes you do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you using some framework.
It is bad way to iterate array, because some frameworks adds functionality to standart prototypes.

```
 for (var i=0, len=arr.length; i<len; ++i) {

 }
```

That code will works anywhere.

Comment: `for..in` is part of the JS spec since JS 1 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: I know. But "for in" array iteration can be used just if you can give the guarantees that noone will change Array.prototype. I think that's not safe.